# Foursquare API v2, authentication, and my now-broken app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, foursquare

I had a developer work on integrating Foursquare into my app (which makes me pretty unfamiliar with the process, but I've been educating myself).  Essentially, it worked like this:

- 4sq short URL was pulled from a Twitter message
- Mechanize was used to unpack the shortened link and grab the venue_id from the full URL
- v1 of the API was queried for location info based on the venue_id from the full URL
- venue info was stored from the API

This was working fine.  It seems like some things at foursquare have recently changed.  First, it seems like I can't get the venue ID from the full URL anymore.  Is that correct, is that a recent change?

I've been looking at v2 of the API.  For those familiar with the API, does it seem like I can accomplish what I was doing before with V2 of the API without having users authorize their Foursquare account?

Any tips here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With V2, you will need to authenticate once and store the auth_token in a db. You can always use the auth_token for subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks @Ved!  I ended up not going the route of using the auth_token and using mechanize to grab what I need from the user's check-in page.